# Easy way to get the weight of a Bricklink order

Tags: piece-information, shopping, bricklink

Is there an easy way to estimate, to the nearest 100 g (or so) the weight of a shopping cart in Bricklink so that I can estimate the shipping charge (sellers may quote ranges such as "250 - 500 g: $X, 500 - 1000 g: $Y" so I wish to stay in a cheaper band if possible)?

I can find out the weight of a type of brick (such as [this](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3010)) but summing by hand is a chore. Just wondering as it already has all the necessary info...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on the MyBrickLink tab on the top row, then My Settings in the second row of tabs, then the My Shopping Settings link. Check the box next to "Show Weight in Shopping Cart". Then, when you view a cart full of items in a particular BrickLink store, scroll to the bottom and it should tell you the calculated total weight.

Comment: http://www.bricklink.com/storeSettings.asp?viewFrom=P is a direct link.

Comment: Not only that, it shows the weight of each part (brick type) — brilliant, thanks :-)

Comment: Remember to allow for packaging materials; 30% of the weight is a rule-of-thumb some people use.