# Can LDD or Studio calculate the weight of your model?

Tags: ldd, bricklink-studio, weight

I have made a model of mine in LDD, and I want to know its weight. Is there any feature in LDD that can calculate the estimated weight of your model? If not, is it available in other software like Studio? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: studio can. Not sure about others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stud.io has that functionality, in the main menu select "Model", and then "Model information", select in the dialog the second tab "Physical information":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: [Export your LDD model to a BrickLink wishlist](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7047/is-there-a-step-by-step-guide-to-extracting-a-parts-list-from-ldd-to-bricklink).

Step 2: Move items from the bricklink wishlist to shopping cart(s) (i.e. find sellers).

Step 3: [See the added weight of your BrickLink shopping carts](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2000/easy-way-to-get-the-weight-of-a-bricklink-order/).

Comment: Step 2 is a bit like [underpants gnomes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5ih_TQWqCA).